# Use variable's value for calling a function/subroutine in AppleScript

Tags: function, variables, applescript

How can I call a function/subroutine in AppleScript using a variable's value? Here is an example of what I want to do (Instead it tries calling "something" function)

```
on HelloWorld()
    display alert "Hello world."
end HelloWorld

set something to "HelloWorld"

something()
```

**I want it to call HelloWorld (the variables value), instead of the variables name "something".**

Answer (score 0):

Correct way to do it is to wrap the handlers in script objects and put them in a searchable list:

```
-- define one or more script objects, each with a custom `doIt()` handler

script HelloWorld
    to doIt()
        display alert "Hello world."
    end doIt
end script

script GoodnightSky
    to doIt()
        say "Goodnight sky."
    end doIt
end script


-- put all the script objects in a list, and define a handler
-- for looking up a script object by name

property _namedObjects : {HelloWorld, GoodnightSky}

to objectForName(objectName)
    repeat with objectRef in _namedObjects
        if objectName is objectRef's name then return objectRef's contents
    end repeat
    error "Can't find object." number -1728 from objectName
end objectForName


-- look up an object by name and send it a `doIt()` command

set something to "HelloWorld"
objectForName(something)'s doIt() -- displays "Hello world"

set something to "GoodnightSky"
objectForName(something)'s doIt() -- says "Goodnight sky"
```